# Consumer triggered entity data agregation

Tags: architecture, architectural-patterns, messaging, rabbitmq, producer-consumer

I am currently using RabbitMQ to aggregate the output of various data sources.

Functionally the process is the following:

1. The user enters a product name.
2. The request is sent to the different sources via RabbitMQ.
3. The results are returned asynchronously.
4. The responses passe through an entity resolution service to make sure that the info corresponds to the product the user is looking for.
5. The user receives the responses as they come.

Here is a simplified diagram

[image]

I presume that this is a pretty common use case and I am looking for best pactices so here are the questions:

1. Is a message broker in general and RabbitMQ, in particular, the right
   tool for consumer triggered processes?
2. What are the possible alternative approaches/architecture designs for consumer triggered processes?
3. Is there any tool or framework out there designed specifically to deal with entity resolution (I am currently using Python both for the machine learning and the rule-based approach)

Comment: It seems to me your second question is too vague. On your firsr question, this tool will work. Can you define what makes a tool "right" in your scenario?